# Browser Back Button click not loading the previous page

Tags: asp.net

I'm working in asp.net, browser back button click is working on all the screens except, where I am loading the new screen from this code.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkActivity1" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink><a href='/Custom/Facility/Activities.aspx?Activity=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID") %>'><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name")%></a>
```

When I click on this link and try to come back it never works.
Please suggest me the workaround for this problem.

Thanks

skharod

Answer (score 0):

```html
<asp:HyperLink ID="MyHyperLinkControl" NavigateUrl="new screen" runat="server">link</asp:HyperLink>
```

`new screen` is your targeted screen

Comment: Hi #Nani, I tried the solution. but not successful. Actually The scenario is                      
1. I'm loading mypage.aspx                  
2. I click on a button to load more contents to the same page                 
3. from the content loaded in the step 2, I Click on a link and going to another page                         
4. When I hit back from the another page it changes the Url but says Webpage Has Expired. Even not going to page load of the previous page                      
5. If I refresh the Page then it open the page in step 1

Comment: Are you using any Cookies